# EndpointConfiguration in Apache camel after 2.19.0 version deprecated

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel, apache-camel-3

In our application we were using older camel version where EndpointConfiguration interface and getEndpointConfiguration() method are referenced [Returns the object representation of the endpoint configuration].

From 2.19.0 camel version we see it's deprecated. Is there any alternate class/method help us in achieving the same functionality. Kindly advise.

Ideally If we get any class/method/method where we can get value at runtime and form the URI dynamically will solve our problem.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. You could still create endpoints dynamically using the uri parameters ? Or you could get the endpoint instance from the component and apply the configuration the you need dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

### In camel3x

the method getEndpointConfiguration() is removed from Endpoint class

the class EndpointConfiguration is  removed

also there is no  getParameter(Stirng parameter) available any where else which can return Endpoint's parameter (as per my knowledge)

Inside my custom processor :-

Previously my code was like

```
Endpoint fromEndpoint = exchange.getFromEndpoint();
String noop=fromEndpoint.getEndpointConfiguration().getParameter("noop");
```

Now in camel3x my code is

```
Endpoint fromEndpoint = exchange.getFromEndpoint();
String fullEndpointUri = fromEndpoint.getEndpointUri();
URI uri = new URI(fullEndpointUri);
Map<String, Object> parameters = URISupport.parseParameters(uri);
String password =(String)parameters.get("noop");
```

If any one have better implementation please advise.